# Connecting Schema-Registry Docker Container to AWS MSK

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, schema, amazon-ecs, aws-msk

I am not able to connect schema registry to MSK. I am running Docker in a separate instance and have connections enabled to MSK services.

Tried docker image from confluent docker.io/confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest.

```
docker run -d \
--net=host 
--name=schema-registry 
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=10.95.21.38:2181 
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry 
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=
http://schema-registry:8081 
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true 
docker.io/confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
```

Error faced when connecting with SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL is below

```
[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand - Error while running kafka-ready.
java.lang.RuntimeException: No endpoints found for security protocol [PLAINTEXT]. Endpoints found in ZK [{REPLICATION=b-1-internal.kafkaclusternew.jbf0pp.c4.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9093, CLIENT=b-1.kafkaclusternew.jbf0pp.c4.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9092, CLIENT_SECURE=b-1.kafkaclusternew.jbf0pp.c4.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9094, REPLICATION_SECURE=b-1-internal.kafkaclusternew.jbf0pp.c4.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9095}]
```

Also tried to replace SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL with SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS

```
  --net=host \
  --name=schema-registry \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://b-2.kafkaclusternew.jbf0pp.c4.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9092,b-3.kafkaclusternew.jbf0pp.c4.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9092,b-1.kafkaclusternew.jbf0pp.c4.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9092 \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081 \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true \
  docker.io/confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
```

Still it failed with below error

```
ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain)
java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
```

Please suggest any fix to this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and had to use

> SCHEMA_REGISTRY_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS

instead of

> SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS

.  Hope that helps.